# Rails ActiveRecord Query: Summarize items by Parent category, when each item only references Subcategory

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need to feed summarized data into a chart library. It should look something like ["parent 1"=> $$$, "parent 2"=> $$$, ... "parent n"=>$$$]

I've got something working with pure SQL, but how do I replicate it with active record?

```
SELECT parents.name, SUM(trxes.amount)
FROM categories as parents
JOIN categories as subcategories ON subcategories.parent_id = parents.id
JOIN trxes ON trxes.category_id = subcategories.id
GROUP BY parents.id
ORDER BY parents.id
=>
[{"name"=>"Income Parent", "SUM(trxes.amount)"=>2270832},
 {"name"=>"Other", "SUM(trxes.amount)"=>1721246},
 {"name"=>"1. Everyday Expenses", "SUM(trxes.amount)"=>-14638},
 {"name"=>"2. Monthly Expenses", "SUM(trxes.amount)"=>-492363},
 {"name"=>"4. Sinking Funds", "SUM(trxes.amount)"=>59742}]
```

The closest I've come is getting the Parent-Category_ID.

```
Category.includes(:trxes).group("categories.parent_id").sum(:amount)
=> {nil=>0, 1=>2270832, 2=>1721246, 3=>-14638, 4=>-492363, 5=>0, 6=>59742, 7=>0}
```

The following query fails with "no such column" error. Its generated SQL call seems to miss the self JOIN of the category table.

```
Category.includes(:trxes).group("categories.parent_id.name").sum(:amount)

Category Sum (0.3ms)
SELECT SUM(amount) AS "sum_amount", categories.parent_id.name AS "categories_parent_id_name"
FROM "categories"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "trxes" ON "trxes"."category_id" = "categories"."id"
GROUP BY categories.parent_id.name

.../database.rb:152:in `initialize': SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: categories.parent_id.name (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)

.../database.rb:152:in `initialize': no such column: categories.parent_id.name (SQLite3::SQLException)
```

Here are my models:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Category", optional: true
  has_many :subcategories, class_name: "Category", foreign_key: :parent_id
  has_many :trxes
...
class Trx < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category, optional: true
...
```

schema.rb

```
  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.integer "parent_id"
    ...
  end
  create_table "trxes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "amount", default: 0, null: false
    t.integer "account_id"
    t.integer "category_id"
    t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_trxes_on_category_id"
    ...
  end
```

Comment: Does `Category.joins(subcategories: :trxes).group(:name).sum(:amount)` work? If not we can write some `Arel` to make the join (or you could just use a String join)

Comment: This appears to work perfectly. => {"1. Everyday Expenses"=>-14638, "2. Monthly Expenses"=>-492363, "4. Sinking Funds"=>59742, "Income Parent"=>2270832, "Other"=>1721246}